# SpringAMQP RabbitMQ how to send directly to Queue without Exchange

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, send, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using SpringAMQP with Rabbit template. How to send messages directly to Queues omitting Exchange? How can i do it?

Answer (score 25):

> How can i do it?

You can't; publishers don't know about queues; just exchanges and routing keys.

However, all queues are bound to the default exchange (`""`) with the queue name as its routing key.

If you are using Spring AMQP's `RabbitTemplate`, it is configured to publish to the default exchange by default, so you can use

```
convertAndSend("myQueue", "foo")`
```

Or even...

```
template.setDefaultRoutingKey("myQueue");
```

then

```
template.convertAndSend("foo");
```

or

```
template.send(aMessage);
```